# How to get console-app argument with no option name in Commons cli?

Tags: java, console-application, apache-commons-cli

This is my console input:

java TCPPing –p –port 9900 –mps 30 –size 1000 pcB

pcB is argument for option with no name.

How do i get pcB argument that has no option?

Small code part:

```
Options options = new Options();
options.addOption("", "hostname", true, "Hostname"); //no option name
options.addOption("port", "port", true, "TCP socket used for connection");

CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
CommandLine commandLine = parser.parse(options, args);

Integer port = Integer.parseInt(cmd.getOptionValue("port")); //works fine
String hostname = cmd.getOptionValue("hostname"); //doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `CommandLine.getArgList()`, or `CommandLine.getArgs()`. They should do what you are looking for, i.e. they return any "leftover" arguments that were not parsed as part of the other options.

```
List<String> args = cmd.getArgList();
```

See https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/cli/CommandLine.html#getArgList-- for the full description.

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping there was a way to parse that argument with empty string but I guess there is not.